# Add a checkbox as WooCommerce admin product option that disables payment gateways

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend, product, payment-gateway

I'm trying to unset COD payment gateway <strike>based on a custom product type</strike> based on the value from the checkbox, added as WooCommerce admin product option.

But it seems the code doesn't do anything with product type: doarcard.

If I set it to simple then it will work:

```php
//new product type 
add_filter("product_type_options", function ($product_type_options) {
        $product_type_options['doarcard'] = array(
            'id' => '_doarcard',
            'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple show_if_variable',
            'label' => __( 'Doar Card', 'woodmart' ),
            'description' => __( 'Activare doar plata cu card sau transfer bancar', 'woodmart' ), 
            'default' => 'no');
             return $product_type_options;
});

add_action("save_post_product", function ($post_ID, $product, $update) {
        update_post_meta(
            $product->ID
            , "_doarcard"
            , isset($_POST["_doarcard"]) ? "yes" : "no");
            }, 10, 3);
//disable cod for doarcard
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditional_payment_gateways', 10, 1);
function conditional_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;
 $prod_doarcard  = false;
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    
        $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
        // Get the product types in cart (example)
        if($product->is_type('doarcard')) $prod_doarcard = true;
        
    }
    if($prod_doarcard)
        unset($available_gateways['cod']); // unset 'cod'
    
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom product type has nothing to do with your question. The value of the checkbox is a boolean with value `yes` or `no`

and based on that you can then unset the `$payment_gateways`

So use:

```php
// Add a checkbox as WooCommerce admin product option
function filter_product_type_options( $product_type_options ) { 
    $product_type_options['doarcard'] = array(
        'id'            => '_doarcard',
        'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple show_if_variable',
        'label'         => __( 'Doar Card', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Activare doar plata cu card sau transfer bancar', 'woocommerce' ),
        'default'       => 'no',
    );

    return $product_type_options;
}
add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'filter_product_type_options', 10, 1 );

// Save checkbox
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {
    $product->update_meta_data( '_doarcard', isset( $_POST['_doarcard'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 10, 1 );

// Payment gateways
function filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $payment_gateways ) {
    // Not on admin
    if ( is_admin() ) return $payment_gateways;
    
    // Initialize
    $prod_doarcard = false;
    
    // WC Cart
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            // Get meta
            $doarcard = $cart_item['data']->get_meta( '_doarcard', true );

            // Equal to yes = checked
            if ( $doarcard == 'yes' ) {
                $prod_doarcard = true;

                // Product present with the right condition, so break the loop
                break;
            }
        }
    
        // True
        if ( $prod_doarcard ) {
            // Cod
            if ( isset( $payment_gateways['cod'] ) ) {
                unset( $payment_gateways['cod'] );
            }  
        }
    }
    
    return $payment_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 10, 1 );
```

---

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

you should use unset inside foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

   $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
   // Get the product types in cart (example)
   if($product->is_type('doarcard')){
       unset($available_gateways['cod']); // unset 'cod'
   } 

 }
```